# I bind the DataTable to DataGridView, but Images does not showing

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, datatable

I bound my datatable to datagridview, every column shows the correct data. But on my Image Column in datagridview does not show the image, instead it shows System.Drawing.Bitmap string.

My codes are;

```
// I create the data column for my Image and add this to the datatable
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("QR Code", typeof(Image));
dc.AllowDBNull = true;
dTable.Columns.Add(dc);

// I loop through all rows in datatable get the byte array of the image, and convert it to an Image
// And then add this image to the newly created column.
foreach (DataRow dr in dTable.Rows)
{
    Image qrCode;
    byte[] qrCodeBytes = (byte[])dr["StockQRCode"];

    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(qrCodeBytes))
    {
        qrCode = Image.FromStream(stream);

        dr[dc] = qrCode;
    }
}
// Bind my datatable to datagridview
List_ListContainer.DataSource = dTable;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: look up how to use this function `Bitmap.FromFile` when adding to DataGridView  this would be implemented using the `Rows.Add()` method for the DataGridView

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I get the DataTable from SqlDataAdapter, so images are not in the specific file path.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to create a special column if you let the DGV autocreate the columns. But basically your code works fine here. Double check the names and try to replace "StockQRCode" by the column index..